# Security of POST request

Tags: java, http, security, post, https

I recently implemented some code which basically sends a POST request to a site, and for security reasons they require an encryption of a `sigToEncrypt` String using SHA256. I have done tests and am confident the below code functions as I intend; I would like to ensure, however, that it is actually secure, as I am still somewhat new to transfer protocols and the related topics.

```
try {

    URI uri;
    String sigToEncrypt;

    // I initialize the sigToEncrypt and uri here (omitting this for SO question)

    // I know this method works as intended
    String signature = generateHMACSHA256Signature(PRIVATE_KEY, sigToEncrypt);

    // Build signed URI w/ encrypted signature (need only for the 'toSend' String)
    URI uriSigned = new URIBuilder(uri).setParameter("signature", signature).build();

    // This is what we actually POST, includes the encrypted signature. Seems hack-y.
    String toSend = uriSigned.toString().substring(uriSigned.toString().indexOf('?') + 1);

    // Here we set up for the post request, specify encoding, public key, etc.
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(POST_URL_STRING);
    httppost.setHeader(KEY_HEADER, PUBLIC_KEY);
    httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", CONTENT_TYPE + "; " + ENCODING);
    // This is the 'important part' of the POST request
    StringEntity se = new StringEntity(toSend);
    httppost.setEntity(se);

    // Make a client so that we can have something to execute our POST from.
    HttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();

    // Here's where we actually execute the post request.
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(httppost); 

    // This returns the result of the request. I know this method works and 
    // that the post was successful.
    result = parseServerResponse(response);

} catch (Exception e) {
    // Do stuff with errors, not pertinent to the question
}
```

Here are my current thoughts on the security of this code:

1. At a first glance, I would think my information would be secure because we encrypt the signature and thus there is no way someone could get any of this information without having the private key, which is only found in my code.
2. At a second glance, I am hesitant about the use of the HttpPost class, as I know `http` is not a secure protocol. However, the URL I am sending to begins with `https`, so maybe I thought maybe it is secure after all (I really am unsure about this, any help as to the security of this and/or how to make it secure would be much appreciated).
3. Last, as less of a thought and more of an inquiry, but if my code does not send POST request securely, is there an api out there that can make it secure? I looked for a while and couldn't seem to find anything that really fit my needs without bending over backwords, so I would be glad to hear of any suggestions you guys have.
4. Finally, even if my code is secure, I seem to always see people on SO using packages/api's for things that they were not meant to do, or that are never updated, etc. This may be the case for the above code, however I would like to do this the 'right' way, and so if my current method could be swapped for a much more painless and 'nice' method of POSTing, I would be all ears.

Like always, I appreciate all the help, leave a comment/question if you need clarification and I should be able to provide it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by trying to determine what the requirement really is - them requiring encryption sounds like them maybe not being sure what are they trying to achieve in the first place :)

Are they trying to encrypt the information in order to protect it from being seen or do they rather want to sign the information in order to protect it from being tampered? You seem to be encrypting some signature - not sure what that means and what's the motivation to do it.

Question 2 - `HttpPost` class refers to HTTP protocol. It has nothing to do with SSL/TLS layer - that is a separate layer from HTTP. So posting this to an `https://` url will make use of SSL/TLS. Things to be careful about - valid certificates, proper TLS configuration, if the endpoint is internet facing use [SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/) to test its configuration.

Question 4 - IMHO implementing this in code is kinda pointless - transport security can be easily achieved by using `https://` - if you need authentication as well you can use client certificates.

Btw I'm kinda missing the point of why are you trying to build what appears to be a query string:

```
// Build signed URI w/ encrypted signature (need only for the 'toSend' String)
URI uriSigned = new URIBuilder(uri).setParameter("signature", signature).build();

// This is what we actually POST, includes the encrypted signature. Seems hack-y.
String toSend = uriSigned.toString().substring(uriSigned.toString().indexOf('?') + 1);
```

Not sure what the `Content-Type` is but IMHO you can POST this in the body as some `application/json` or whatever else that works for you. If you want to post that as `text/plain` or maybe `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` you can just do:

Instead of that code I mentioned, you can just use this and it will do the same thing as it does now:

```
StringEntity se = new StringEntity("signature=" + URLEncoder.encode(signature, ENCODING));
```

which is this:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Key-Header: public_key_here
Content-Type: application/something; utf8
Content-Length: 19
Host: 127.0.0.1
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.6
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Connection: close

signature=signature
```

And that works fine - I'd say it depends on the server (other side) and what `Content-Type` does it expect.

Comment: Thanks for the response! The data I encrypt has personal information in it, so I would think they would want it to be encrypted for both of the reasons you gave. I'm also glad to know that SSL/TLS is utilized here. As for the sloppiness of my code, to get this to work I was sort of just trying many different things until something worked, that's why I asked if it was the best way. Would you happen to have any links/code showing how to execute POST in a better way?

Comment: I updated the answer with what I meant by that query string thing. Now it all depends on the other side and what Content-Type does it expect to be receiving - your code does not show the CONTENT_TYPE variable content.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much for clearing that up. Glad to know my implementation was at the very least secure.